# Electron build for Centos in AppImage format is not running on double click or enter

Tags: electron, centos7, sandbox, electron-builder

My electron build for linux in AppImage format is not running on double click or enter. I have also tried to run it through the terminal but it is showing following message.

"The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /tmp/.mount_Kiosk-hsmPb8/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755."

It is perfectly running through the terminal by adding --no-sandbox after filename.

I want to execute the AppImage in Centos7 by double click or enter. Please help